# Disable context menu on certain ListView items

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with a `ContextMenu` associated with each item in the `ListView`.

Is it possible to disable the `ContextMenu` for specific items?

Comment: override, onPrepareContextMenu()/onCreateContextMenu(), for the particular listview item, just return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue before, following is my solution:
I set my `ListView`'s `OnItemLongClickListener` as following:

```
private OnItemLongClickListener mBookLongClickListener = new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int id,
            long arg3) {
        showBookDialog(view, id);
        return true;
    }
};
```

In the method `showBookDialog()`: According to the user's current item, I create an `AlertDialog` with option list(something like menu) or show nothing at all.

Comment: Vamsi's answer worked for me, but I'll give your props for answering. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onCreateContextMenu(menu: ContextMenu, v: View, menuInfo: ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo?) {
    if(showContextMenu) {
        // inflate the menu layout
    }
    else {
        return; // this will show noting, but click action will continue
    }
}
```

Comment: This piece of code is working for me. I will comment for clarification.